# Converting a sequence of images to a video from terminal

Tags: command-line

Is there a way to convert a sequence of images to a video from terminal? Specifically, the sequence of images are in `.eps` format (`filename_1.eps`,`filename_2.eps`,...,`filename_99.eps`,`filename_100.eps`) and I want to convert them to `.avi` format i.e. to `filename.avi`.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about `.eps` but you need 2 tools for this:

> Installation

1. [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install imagemagick
   ```
2. [mpeg2enc](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/mpeg2vidcodec_v12.tar.gz)

   ```
   wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/mpeg2vidcodec_v12.tar.gz
   tar xvzf mpeg2vidcodec_v12.tar.gz
   cd mpeg2
   ./configure
   make
   ```

   Copy then `tmpeg2enc` contents to /usr/bin:

   ```
   sudo mv mpeg2/src/mpeg2enc /usr/bin
   ```

---

> Creating a move sequence from images

```
 convert -delay 20 *.eps video.avi
```

> Convert .eps

In case .eps is not supported you can convert them to another format with

```
convert image.eps image.png
```

Comment: I get this error.
`convert: no encode delegate for this image format filename.avi @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1188.`

Comment: ha! you probably need `ffmpeg`. I already have this installed. (or the new AVCONV)

Comment: I have ffmpeg also installed.